# how to make block of 2 headers responsive and <p> in front of image too

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I want to make responsive 2 headers and the paragraph tag, the problem is the background of

is an image, so That should be responsive too? And if I put an image inside, maybe herency is the way to go

I have tried modifying it but had no luck, I understand that making the widgt and height  with percentages can solve the responsiveness, but how to do it

```
<header id="wrapper">
    <div class="container clearfix">
         <h1 id="logo" class="alignleft"> <a href="index.html"></a> </h1>

        <div id="head-two"> <a href="http://www.twitter.com/"><img src="http://poledancescool.com/images/twitterlogo.png"  class="rollOut" width="55" height="55" alt="" style="" /></a>
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com/"><img src="http://poledancescool.com/images/facebooklogo2.png" class="rollOut"  width="55" height="55" alt="" /></a>

        </div>
        <br/>
        <div style="justify;" class="fadeInDown">
                <h1>some slogan to response screen size...</h1>

            <br />
                <h3>        yes it is!</h3>

        </div>
    </div>
</header>
<div class="section ancor">
    <div class="first-heading"></div>
</div>
<div id="primary">
    <div id="left">
        <div id="object1" align='justify'>
            <br/>
            <br/>
            <p>Bla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla BlaBla Bla Bla</p>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="right">
        <div id="object3">
<b><h2>title</h2></b>

            <img class="align-right" alt="" src="images/poledance/dance5.jpg" class="fadeInDown" style=" width=82%; height=82%; " />
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

So this looks like
[image]

I would like to be responsive and look like:
[image]

But I am currently getting:

[image]

[the result can be seen here](http://jsfiddle.net/NUgEf/11/embedded/result/)

What woul be the best approach to add responsiveness?
[please take a look at a the fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/NUgEf/11/)

What could I make to make responsive the gray rectangle?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Editied fiddle, just commented #left,#right magin & padding. Please check.

Comment: where can I find the edited fiddle? could you please point it out=

Comment: see #left, #right {
    width: 47%;
/*    margin:2px;
    padding: 1em;*/
}

Comment: mine edit was not complete, you need to work more on it. Sorry